# Error while trying to use angularjs interceptors Uncaught getting Cannot call method 'push' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, frontend

I am using Angularjs 1.2.0rc1. The all day i have been trying to get angular interceptors to work. I have narrowed down the problem to be that $httpProvider.interceptors.push seem to be undefined, I have no clue why, Everything else is working fine.

The following is sample code:

```
services.factory('testInterceptor', function ($q) {
return {    
  'response': function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    return response || $q.when(response);
  },     
  'responseError': function(rejection) {
    console.log(rejection);
    return $q.reject(rejection);
  }
};
});
```

in the `module.config` I have the following code.

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('testInterceptor');
```

if I delete the above code, the application works fine, however if its present , i keep on getting this error on my console

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined from
>   myModule."

`myModule` is the name of the module.

**Please do note that, from my investigation "$httpProvider.interceptors" seems to be undefined, i have no clue as to why it is, any insight would be helpful.**

I appreciate any assistance/hints your might have.

Comment: Could you please provide more info about how your modules are boostraped together? I made a small test and everything works fine: http://plnkr.co/edit/s3ld5b?p=preview

Comment: Hi Jonas, Thanks alot for the answer, i have somehow managed to solve it .The issue was that grunt build was using google CDN for the angular framework , it was loading an old version of angularjs,to be specific angular 1.0.7.

Comment: @EricK your suggestion worked for me too.

Answer (score 1):

Does your config looks like below?

```
myModule.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('testInterceptor');
}]);
```

I use the interceptor, but inline leading to this code:

```
myModule.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q) {
    return {
        // optional method
        'request': function(config) {
            return config || $q.when(config);
        },

        // optional method
        'requestError': function(rejection) {
            return $q.reject(rejection);
        },

        // optional method
        'response': function(response) {
            return response || $q.when(response);
        },

        // optional method
        'responseError': function(rejection) {
            return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
    }
  })
}]);
```

But i never seem to get into requestError or responseError, even if the server throws a 500 error, but that looks like another problem. Hope this code sample helps.